# Restarting Android App occasionally throws java.lang.IllegalStateException

Tags: android, sqlite

When I'm restarting an app through Android studio, occasionally this exception will occur and the only way I've found to resolve it is to clear the data stored within the app.

```
java.lang.IllegalStateException: Couldn't read row 0, col 0 from CursorWindow.  Make sure the Cursor is initialized correctly before accessing data from it.
```

I assume this occurs because the app is being killed in the middle of a transaction to my sqlite database.

1. Is my assumption correct?
2. Is there any way to prevent this from happen?
3. If my app runs a service in the foreground and it gets killed in order to update the app itself could this happen?

Edit:

```
STACK_TRACE=java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.camhart.netcountable/com.camhart.netcountable.activities.setup.DeviceTypeActivity}: java.lang.IllegalStateException: Couldn't read row 0, col 0 from CursorWindow.  Make sure the Cursor is initialized correctly before accessing data from it.
at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:3254)
at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:3350)
at android.app.ActivityThread.access$1100(ActivityThread.java:222)
at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1795)
at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:158)
at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:7229)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1230)
at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:1120)
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalStateException: Couldn't read row 0, col 0 from CursorWindow.  Make sure the Cursor is initialized correctly before accessing data from it.
at android.database.CursorWindow.nativeGetLong(Native Method)
at android.database.CursorWindow.getLong(CursorWindow.java:524)
at android.database.AbstractWindowedCursor.getLong(AbstractWindowedCursor.java:75)
at com.camhart.netcountable.sqlite.dataaccess.SettingDataAccess.getSettings(SettingDataAccess.java:91)
at com.camhart.netcountable.sqlite.businesslogic.SettingBusinessLogic.getSettingsFromDatabase(SettingBusinessLogic.java:61)
at com.camhart.netcountable.sqlite.businesslogic.SettingBusinessLogic.getSetting(SettingBusinessLogic.java:54)
at com.camhart.netcountable.activities.setup.DeviceTypeActivity.onCreate(DeviceTypeActivity.java:43)
at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:6876)
at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1135)
at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:3207)
... 9 more
java.lang.IllegalStateException: Couldn't read row 0, col 0 from CursorWindow.  Make sure the Cursor is initialized correctly before accessing data from it.
at android.database.CursorWindow.nativeGetLong(Native Method)
at android.database.CursorWindow.getLong(CursorWindow.java:524)
at android.database.AbstractWindowedCursor.getLong(AbstractWindowedCursor.java:75)
at com.camhart.netcountable.sqlite.dataaccess.SettingDataAccess.getSettings(SettingDataAccess.java:91)
at com.camhart.netcountable.sqlite.businesslogic.SettingBusinessLogic.getSettingsFromDatabase(SettingBusinessLogic.java:61)
at com.camhart.netcountable.sqlite.businesslogic.SettingBusinessLogic.getSetting(SettingBusinessLogic.java:54)
at com.camhart.netcountable.activities.setup.DeviceTypeActivity.onCreate(DeviceTypeActivity.java:43)
at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:6876)
at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1135)
at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:3207)
at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:3350)
at android.app.ActivityThread.access$1100(ActivityThread.java:222)
at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1795)
at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:158)
at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:7229)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1230)
at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:1120)
```

SettingDataAccess.java

```
package com.camhart.netcountable.sqlite.dataaccess;

import android.content.ContentValues;
import android.content.Context;
import android.database.Cursor;

import com.camhart.netcountable.sqlite.models.Setting;
import com.camhart.netcountable.sqlite.tabledata.SettingTableData;

import net.openid.appauth.AuthState;

import org.json.JSONException;

public class SettingDataAccess extends DataAccess {

    \\...

    private static String[] columnsToGrab = new String[]{
            SettingTableData._ID,
            SettingTableData.COLUMN_NAME_USERNAME,
            SettingTableData.COLUMN_NAME_ACCOUNTID,
            SettingTableData.COLUMN_NAME_IDENTITYID,
            SettingTableData.COLUMN_NAME_WIFIONLY,
            SettingTableData.COLUMN_NAME_EMAIL,
            SettingTableData.COLUMN_NAME_ADMINDEVICE,
            SettingTableData.COLUMN_NAME_PREMIUM,
            SettingTableData.COLUMN_NAME_PUBLICKEY,
            SettingTableData.COLUMN_NAME_TAKENAPSHOTS,
            SettingTableData.COLUMN_NAME_AUTHSTATEJSON
    };

    public Setting getSettings() {
        Setting setting = new Setting();

        Cursor c = db.query(SettingTableData.TABLE_NAME,
                columnsToGrab,
                null,
                new String[]{},
                null,
                null,
                null,
                null);

        if(c.moveToFirst()) {
            setting.setId(c.getLong(c.getColumnIndex(SettingTableData._ID)));   //#line 91
            setting.setAccountId(c.getString(c.getColumnIndex(SettingTableData.COLUMN_NAME_ACCOUNTID)));
            setting.setIdentityId(c.getString(c.getColumnIndex(SettingTableData.COLUMN_NAME_IDENTITYID)));
            setting.setDisplayName(c.getString(c.getColumnIndex(SettingTableData.COLUMN_NAME_USERNAME)));
            setting.setWifiOnlyUpload(c.getInt(c.getColumnIndex(SettingTableData.COLUMN_NAME_WIFIONLY)) == 1);
            setting.setEmail(c.getString(c.getColumnIndex(SettingTableData.COLUMN_NAME_EMAIL)));

            setting.setAdminDevice(c.getInt(c.getColumnIndex(SettingTableData.COLUMN_NAME_ADMINDEVICE)) == 1);
            setting.setPremium(c.getInt(c.getColumnIndex(SettingTableData.COLUMN_NAME_PREMIUM)) == 1);
            setting.setPublicKey(c.getString(c.getColumnIndex(SettingTableData.COLUMN_NAME_PUBLICKEY)));
            setting.setTakeSnapshots(c.getInt(c.getColumnIndex(SettingTableData.COLUMN_NAME_TAKENAPSHOTS)) == 1);
            String jsonAuthState = c.getString(c.getColumnIndex(SettingTableData.COLUMN_NAME_AUTHSTATEJSON));

            if(jsonAuthState != null) {
                try {
                    setting.setAuthState(AuthState.jsonDeserialize(jsonAuthState));
                } catch (JSONException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            }
            c.close();

            return setting;
        }
        c.close();

        return null;
    }
}
```

SettingTableData.java

```
public class SettingTableData implements BaseColumns {
    public static final String TABLE_NAME = "settings";
    public static final String COLUMN_NAME_WIFIONLY = "wifiOnlyUpload";
    public static final String COLUMN_NAME_USERNAME = "username";
    public static final String COLUMN_NAME_ACCOUNTID = "accountId";
    public static final String COLUMN_NAME_IDENTITYID = "identityId";
    public static final String COLUMN_NAME_EMAIL = "email";
    public static final String COLUMN_NAME_PREMIUM = "premium";
    public static final String COLUMN_NAME_LASTREFRESH = "lastRefresh";
//    public static final String COLUMN_NAME_PRIVATEKEY = "privateKey";
    public static final String COLUMN_NAME_ADMINDEVICE = "admin";
    public static final String COLUMN_NAME_PUBLICKEY = "publicKey";
    public static final String COLUMN_NAME_TAKENAPSHOTS = "takeSnapshots";
    public static final String COLUMN_NAME_AUTHSTATEJSON = "jsonAuthState";
}
```

Setting.java

```
public class Setting {

    private boolean wifiOnlyUpload;
    private String displayName;
    private String accountId;
    private String identityId;
    private long id;
    private String email;
    private boolean premium;
    private boolean adminDevice;
    private String publicKey;
    private boolean takeSnapshots;
    private AuthState authState;

    public String getIdentityId() {
        return identityId;
    }

    public void setIdentityId(String identityId) {
        this.identityId = identityId;
    }

    public String getAccountId() {
        return accountId;
    }

    public void setAccountId(String accountId) {
        this.accountId = accountId;
    }

    public boolean isWifiOnlyUpload() {
        return wifiOnlyUpload;
    }

    public void setWifiOnlyUpload(boolean wifiOnlyUpload) {
        this.wifiOnlyUpload = wifiOnlyUpload;
    }

    public String getDisplayName() {
        return displayName;
    }

    public void setDisplayName(String username) {
        this.displayName = username;
    }

    public long getId() {
        return id;
    }

    public void setId(long id) {
        this.id = id;
    }

    public void setEmail(String email) {
        this.email = email;
    }

    public String getEmail() {
        return email;
    }

    public boolean isPremium() {
        return premium;
    }

    public void setPremium(boolean premium) {
        this.premium = premium;
    }

    public boolean isAdminDevice() {
        return adminDevice;
    }

    public void setAdminDevice(boolean adminDevice) {
        this.adminDevice = adminDevice;
    }

    public void setPublicKey(String publicToken) {
        this.publicKey = publicToken;
    }

    public String getPublicKey() {
        return this.publicKey;
    }

    public boolean takesSnapshots() {
        //TODO: Make it so admins can take screenies too (for couples)
        return isTakeSnapshots() && isPremium();
    }

    public void setTakeSnapshots(boolean takeSnapshots) {
        this.takeSnapshots = takeSnapshots;
    }

    public boolean isTakeSnapshots() {
        return takeSnapshots;
    }

    public AuthState getAuthState() {
        return authState;
    }

    public void setAuthState(AuthState jsonAuthState) {
        this.authState = jsonAuthState;
    }

    //TODO:  update this to save the device type, then just have this check for isOwnerDevice instead of
    // having to check the auth state too.
    public boolean isOwner() {
        return getAuthState() != null && isAdminDevice();
    }

    public String getReversedIdentityId() {
        return new StringBuilder(getIdentityId()).reverse().toString();
    }
}
```

DataAccess.java

```
public class DataAccess {
    protected SQLiteDatabase db;
    private static DbHelper dbHandler;

    protected static synchronized DbHelper getDbHelper(Context context) {
        if(dbHandler == null) {
            dbHandler = new DbHelper(context);
        }
        return dbHandler;
    }

    public DataAccess(Context context) {
        if(dbHandler == null) {
            dbHandler = getDbHelper(context);
        }
    }

    public void open() throws SQLException {
        db = dbHandler.getWritableDatabase();
    }

    public void close() {
        db.close();
        db = null;
    }
}
```

Comment: We need more information to help you. Please post the entire stacktrace and any relevant code.

Comment: This has nothing to do with transactions.

Comment: I'm waiting for the error to occur again and then I'll update with code and a full stack trace.

Comment: Please post complete code. The method should be inside a class. Also include all required variable declarations and initializations.

Comment: @Code-Apprentice done.

Comment: Some variable declarations are still missing. You also added several method which seem irrelevant to your question.

Comment: And the comment showing line 91 is gone.

Comment: @Code-Apprentice I think everything you might need is in there.  Thanks.

Comment: I still do not see the declaration for db.

Comment: @Code-Apprentice hopefully the last time :D

Comment: More importantly, you need to determine if getColumnIndex() or getLong() causes the crash. Also does the crash only occur when the app is already running and you run it again from AS?

Comment: The app runs great...  then occasionally I'll restart the app using AS, and then the app won't run whether it's started from AS or locally on the phone (I get the same error message).  To me it seems like the database is getting broken somehow.  Like it was in the middle of something when it was restarted and that corrupted it. @Code-Apprentice

Comment: @CamHart to test your hypothesis, use `adb shell`  to view your database.

Comment: https://developer.android.com/studio/command-line/sqlite3.html

Comment: I'm using samsung galaxy s6... it doesn't have sqlite3 installed, and I don't have permissions to pull the database out...  And I can't seem to get adb root access to work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It appears what's happening is my auth state json string is much much longer than I anticipated it would be.  I moved it over to a SharedPreference location and after some time I started to get OOM whenever I attempted to load it.  I think this may be whats going on with it in Sqlite.